# best way to install a library on azure databricks

Tags: python, azure, jupyter-notebook, databricks, azure-databricks

I need to install azure library on my azure databricks. Right now I am installing it globally but sometime when cluster starts my notebook fails with error as below:

AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'SSL_ST_INIT'

what should be the best way to install a library on azure databricks, install it globally or install it locally on each notebook using dbutils.library.installPyPI(lib,version) ?

Answer (score 1):

there are an existing SO thread [Databricks cluster does not initialize Azure library with error: module 'lib' has no attribute 'SSL_ST_INIT'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54984230/databricks-cluster-does-not-initialize-azure-library-with-error-module-lib-ha) with the same issue and a similar SO thread [Python AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSL_ST_INIT'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43267157/python-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-ssl-st-init), which you may refer to.

To downgrade a Python library, please first to uninstall it and then to install with the specified version, for example as below.

1. `pip uninstall azure`
2. `pip install azure==3.0.0`

For more details about how to install libraries on Azure Databricks, please see the offical topic [`Libraries`](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/libraries.html).

Comment: I have gone through all these threads already. My question is what is the best way/practice to install a library on databricks, globally or locally?

Comment: @shubhamnayak There is no standard answer for what the best way is. It's up to you and your scenario. The section [`Library lifecycles
`](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/libraries.html#library-lifecycles) is partial answer based on usage scope I think.